# How to get (MahApps) metro style in derived control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I create my own control to look and act like `ComboBox`.

Approach A: I create UserControl with `ComboBox` as a content. It HAS the metro style, it looks perfect. It works. However I have to manually recreate `ComboBox` properties in my control. A lot of redundant, ugly code.

Approach B: I extend `ComboBox` control itself, so no extra coding is needed. It works as charm, however - it's a `ComboBox` with a different name, so it's not targeted with the metro style for `ComboBox`.

How to make my new derived control use the metro style for `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 0):

Add an implicit style to your `App.xaml` file (replace `CustomComboBox` with the name of your derived class):

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroComboBox}" />
```

If you are using the Material Design toolkit, it should be:

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBox}" />
```